# Memcached in Munin

Tags: ubuntu, memcached, munin

I tried to configure the munin to load the memcached plugin. But the memcached plugin wont show up when I add the `--suggest` to the 
`munin-node-configure` command. But I appear when I do not add that xtra command.

I have added this to the `/etc/munin/plugin-conf.d/memcached`

```
[memcached_*] 
env.host 127.0.0.1 
env.port 11211 
env.timescale 3
```

I'm running

- Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS.
- Munin version 1.4.6.
- Memcached version 1.4.13

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Debugging

You can debug the plugin by using the "munin-run" command, optionally with "--debug" and "--pidebug" parameters.

## Check for dependencies

On a default installation, it will say:

```
# /usr/sbin/munin-run --servicedir /usr/share/munin/plugins/ memcached_ autoconf
no (Cache::Memcached not found)
```

This perl library is found in the libcache-memcached-perl package.  If this is installed, the "autoconf" commandline should say:

```
# /usr/sbin/munin-run --servicedir /usr/share/munin/plugins/ memcached_ autoconf
yes
```

## Installing the memcached_ plugin

The memcached_ plugin lacks complete "autoconf" and "suggest" capabilities, so it will not be configured by "munin-node-configure".  You need to symlink manually, and add the dataset name to the end of the link:

```
ln -s /usr/share/munin/plugins/memcached_ /etc/munin/plugins/memcached_FOO
```

Restart the munin node afterwards.